# make each line of array an individual string php

Tags: php, arrays, string, implode

I am working on making only picture files appear as pictures instead of links when scanning a directory.  Here is what I am using to find the files:

```
$images=glob(getcwd().'/*{jpeg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
$pattern=implode("<br>", $images)."<br>";
```

This gives me this:

```
/students/levans10/public_html/cs130a/images.gif
/students/levans10/public_html/cs130a/jpg-44.png
```

How can I refer to each one of those lines as a string?

Here is my entire code that is not working for me:

```
<?php

function showImage() {
$filelist = glob(getcwd()."/*");
$path= getcwd();
$array = explode("/", $path);
$filename=implode("/", array_slice($array, 4));
$user=implode("/", array_slice($array, 2, 1));
$images=glob(getcwd().'/*{jpeg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
$pattern=implode("<br>", $images)."<br>";

echo implode("<br>", $images);

if ($filelist != false) {
print "<p>Here are the folders and files in".getcwd().":</p>";
foreach ($filelist as $file) {
  if(ereg($pattern, $file)) {
  $url = "http://hills.ccsf.edu/~".$user."/".$filename."/" . substr($file, strrpos($file, '/') + 1);
  print "<a href=".$url."><img src=".$url." height='100' width='100'></a><br><br>";
       }
  if(!ereg($pattern, $file)) {
  $url = "http://hills.ccsf.edu/~".$user."/".$filename."/" . substr($file, strrpos($file, '/') + 1);
  print "<a href=".$url.">".$url."</a><br><br>";        
    }
}
} else {
print "<a href=".$url.">".$url."</a><br><br>";
}
}

showImage();

?>
```

I tried using:
    `(!feofif(ereg($pattern, $file))))`

But that is not the proper use of !feof so it displays the pics but then issues a ton of other warnings.

Comment: If you absolutely need individual string variables rather than an array of strings, then [extract()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Comment: Huii, what is your goal here? What is your output and expected output?

Comment: goal is to scan files in a directory and display all image files as small images that are links and all non image files as urls.  This link shows the output of my code [link](http://hills.ccsf.edu/~levans10/cs130a/showImage.php)  I would like the two image files to show as pictures.

Comment: @MarkBaker I am looking into extract() now, thanks!

Comment: But why can't you simply iterate over the returned array, it looks as though you're making this far more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: @MarkBaker because I am not sure how to since I am already in a foreach loop.  I use the foreach loop to look through all the files but then I am struggling to search through the returned files again and only pull up the image files.

Comment: Please add an example with some files and what the expected output would be

Comment: @w3d because when I try to use the array directly with ereg I get a array to string conversion error message. And I thought I need the foreach loop to get all of the files returned.

Comment: @Rizier123 there is a link I posted in my first comment that will show the output.  I would like the links that are image files to display as small pictures instead of links.

Comment: As a "quick fix" you could probably just change `if(ereg($pattern, $file)) {` with `if (in_array($file,$images)) {`. (?) And enclose the 2nd part in an `else` block, don't use another `if` and negate the expression!

Comment: @w3d thank you, that worked.  Thanks for all the feedback.  I apologize if this is not the cleanest code or if it was unclear, I am just beginning to learn how to program.

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to display links to all the files, but for images you want to display the image as well. The fact that you wanted to still link to all your files seemed to be the missing nugget of information in your question *description*.

As mentioned, in comments, a "quick fix" is just to change `if(ereg($pattern, $file)) {` with `if (in_array($file,$images)) {`. And enclose the 2nd part in an else block, don't use another if and negate the expression! In other words...

```
if (in_array($file,$images)) {
    /* Link and display image */
} else {
    /* Just link the file */
}
```

Alternatively, you could just check each file if it's an image as you step through your `$filelist`, rather than doing this before your loop (and storing these files in another array called `$images` which you then need to lookup). And avoid code repetition by moving your `$url` assignment outside of your `if` block. For example:

```
$url = '<Construct URL before IF block>';
if (preg_match('/\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$/i',$file)) {
    /* Link and display image */
} else {
    /* Just link the file */
}
```

(Don't use `ereg()` to match a regular expression - this function was deprecated in PHP 5.3. Use `preg_replace()` instead.)

If you must construct your HTML in this way then build it up in a string variable and `echo` this once when you have finished (at the end of your loop). Don't echo, echo, echo, etc. For example:

```
$html = '';
foreach ($filelist as $file) {
    /* ... */
    $html .= '<Some HTML>';
    /* ... */
    $html .= '<Some more HTML>';
}
echo $html;
```